# Http redirect to https using .htaccess file not working for non www. to non www

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I recently setup SSL and added a redirect in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]
```

The http and https with www. get redirected to the non www. https domain for the root domain and other pages which is what I want.

But http with non www. only gets redirected if it's the root domain. Any other pages don't get redirected.

e.g. 
http://rankhigherseo.com.au/ gets redirected but http://rankhigherseo.com.au/about-us/ doesn't get redirected

Anyone know why?

Comment: `http://rankhigherseo.com.au/about-us/` currently redirects me to `https://rankhigherseo.com.au/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/rankhigherseo.com.au//about-us//_index.html_gzip` ... so it looks like you have other stuff interfering here.

Comment: Thought I fixed that. Seems like I diddn't...

Comment: @CBroe can you check if it still redirects to that page. If not can you double check in a different browser. Would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Nope, seems to work fine now, redirects me from the HTTP to the HTTPS version of that URL.